# How to properly install graphics drivers in 12.10

Tags: 12.10, drivers, nvidia, graphics, resolution

Okay so im new to linux operating systems and im having trouble installing my graphics driver I asked a question before but I'm going to try to be more specific this time.

I have a 19.5 inch monitor and im using a GTX 550Ti gf card and ive tried multiple ways of installing my drivers. BUT I fear that I might of tried to many ways and one of them worked but I dont really know how to remove them. So could someone PLEASE explain how to removed and install my drivers properly? ( the problem I have is not getting a high enough resolution. and it tends to make my mouse not work properly in some screens I get stuck at  1024 X 768)

Answer (score 0):

I find jockey-gtk the best tool to install and remove graphics drivers. I do not whey they removed it from 12.10. Search in the software center and install it. If it is available then you are done. Use it to install the drives. If not let us know.

Comment: It is not removed in 12.10. It is there in software sources, addtional driver tab

Comment: Well I used it but still no resolution fix...I tried many of the choices as well and restarted my comp after each one.